# How to keep my filter after click to another pagination item

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'v this in my controller after my query I paginate the itens to show in my view:

```
        $format        = Input::get('format', 'html');
        $funcionario   = Input::get('filter_funcionario');

        $filter_funcionarios = $this->funcionario->lists('nome', 'cod');

        //initialize query to DB
        $horariosQuery = $this->horario->with(array('funcionario', 'item_contabil'))->orderby('cod', 'ASC');

        if ($funcionario)
        {               
            $horariosQuery->where('cod_funcionario', $funcionario);
        }

        $horariosQuery->where('validado', 0)
                      ->orWhere('motivo', '<>', '')
                      ->orderBy('data');

        $horariosQuery->whereNull('deleted_at');               

        $horarios = $horariosQuery->paginate(40);

        $data = array(
            'horarios'  => $horarios,
            'filter_funcionarios' => (array( 0 =>'Selecione um funcionario') + $filter_funcionarios),
            'funcionario' => $funcionario,
        );

    return View::make('horarios.inconsistencia', $data);
```

But when I aplly a filter and change the page, the page changes to number to but I loss my employee filter

How could I change the page but keep the filter in the page ? its possible do to somenthing like this using pagination?
thx in advance!

---

answer :

that solved for me, get all inputs and append to the link

```
{{ $horarios->appends(Input::get())->links() }}
```

thx for the help!

Comment: What is `employee` filter, where it's here in this code ?

Comment: funcionario is employee, sorry about it I forgot to explain this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append your filter to the pagination links like this:

```
{{ $horarios->appends('filter'=>'someValue')->links() }}
```

or if it is hash fragment of the url then:

```
{{ $horarios->fragment('someValue')->links() }}
```

Of course filter => someValue replace with your actual filter data.